How to calculate PCB area size for Triac
I am using a BTA40-600B in a RD91 package to control an resistive load. My max current thru the triac will be 12 A - 120 V AC. According to the data sheet, P(W) for 12 A is 12 W.  Junction to case is .9 C/W.  Junction to ambient is 50 C/W. The PCB is two sided using 2 oz copper. I could also use a BTA25-600B instead if it helps - same price.
I've researched all kinds of documents on how to figure thermal resistance to PCB area to directly mount the RD91 package to the PCB with GND planes on both sides of the board and multiple thermal vias to connect the two, and I'm totally lost.
Can someone point me in the right direction so I can see what PCB area on both sides of the board is required to dissipate the 12 W of heat? I would like to understand so I can vary area vs temp rise in the PCB.

Rja doesn't matter but Rjc=0.9 does matter (insulated case) what is your max ambient or board temp and max Tj= 80'C is recommended with abs. max. @ 125'C and lower MTBF. Is it enclosed? what is Rth of enclosure? normally 1 sqin/W of 2S 2oz

https://www.ti.com/design-resources/design-tools-simulation/models-simulators/pcb-thermal-calculator.html

Thanks.  Max ambient is 30C.  The board is suspended in a large 8 ft3 so I would say that Rth of the enclosure could be ignored.  I would like max Tj to be 80C.  I looked into the tool you recommended but it did not provide options for my package or the fact I'm using 2oz copper on both sides of the board or that it expects the package to be soldered to the PCB.  My RD91 will have thermal pasted and be secured to the PCB via nut/bolt.  Do you have a recommended area (combined top and bottom) that would meet my requirements?

I would use a sink & quiet fan at a quiet speed in a small package which could reduce area significantly.
Otherwise I recall(?) Tj= 85'C (rise = 60)with 1sq.in/W  = 12 sq.in. or ~ 78 cm^2.
If the board plane is vertical it will support convection cooling better and drop below Tj=80 I believe . Use Tc + Rjc*P = Tj or calibrate voltage drop with oven temp to act as a thermocouple for jcn.  Your method makes it hard to test.

you also need a bunch of "thermal vias"

An obsolete TI document also cited 2oz 2S FR4 1/16" with thermal vias was 50 C/W/in^2
http://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/archive/2016/06/10/understanding-mosfet-data-sheets-part-6-thermal-impedance

Thanks - I will go with a big external heat sink and NOT try to use my PCB as the heat sink.

Insulated case with an old CPU sink & low speed fan will run cool
